# Shrink double if statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot use the following statement because `x` and `y` may be defined as `None`:

```
if x*y > 9:
    pass
```

`unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

So I should check first for the existence:

```
if x and y:
    if x*y > 9:
        pass
```

It seems a bit redundant. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean `x` and `y` may not be defined at all or that they may be defined as `None` rather than as float/ints/Booleans? You seem to ask about the first but the error is about the second.

Comment: a try/except is needed if x or y doesn't exist at all

Comment: @RoryDaulton I updated my question, thanks. They may be defined as `None`.

Comment: It does not really make a difference here, but in general I would check for `x is None` instead of just `x`, as `x` might be zero (also, you make more explicit what the check is for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
if x and y and x*y > 9:
    pass
```

If you get even more checks it might be more comfortable to use `all`:

```
if all([
    x,
    y,
    x*y > 9,
    other conditions,...]):
    pass
```

Comment: `all` solution does not work because `x*y > 9` will be evaluated whiling making the list.

Comment: Yea you are right. `all` does short-circuit, but the list creation is the problem. I wonder if there is a pretty solution...?

Answer (score 3):

Following the [**EAFP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) (***E**asier to **A**sk **F**orgiveness than **P**ermission*) protocol, here's an alternative using try and except:

```
try:
   if x * y > 9:
       pass
except TypeError:
   pass
```

Answer (score 2):

While `if x and y and x * y > 9:` is the most straightforward way, an alternative I find satisfying in an hard to define way is to use defaults for `x` and `y` when they're falsy:

```
if (x or 0) * (y or 0) > 9:
```

Since replacing either value with 0 makes the result 0, the test doesn't pass, as expected, when either value is `None`. This works because Python boolean `and` and `or` don't return `True` or `False` they return the last value evaluated (which will be truthy or falsy already). So if `x` is a non-zero number, you use `x`, otherwise you use `0`, and same goes for `y`.